# some times i have seen that lags on a particular kafka topics increasing for a particuar consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

scenario
I have a topic with 8 partitions and data is coming aproximatly 10k per sec and have set up a s3 consumer on top of it, the consumer is working but the problem is lag on a particular partition is increasing continuously, currently have 510k+ lag on this partition and on other partitions, it is less than 1.5k

thanks in advance any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It'd be great if you could show your connector configuration

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.